# Get distance from kinect depth image using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and opencv

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, kinect, robotics

I found out from one site that it is possible to find distance from the raw depth video output of the Kinect through the 2 bytes assigned to a particular pixel as shown in this link - [tutorial](http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/practical-windows-kinect-in-c/3802-using-the-kinect-depth-sensor.html). Based on this I written a code to find out the distance of the middle point form the Kinect sensor.

I compiled it and ran the code on Ubuntu and it is showing the output. The output is showing some values as distance. The values are coming around 150->1147. I hope it is showing the distance in mm.

But I am not sure, if it is right or wrong. I am providing the code below. Is my code working correctly or do I need to make some changes?

**Code:**

```
    #include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv/highgui.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "libfreenect_cv.h"

    int getDist(IplImage *depth){
      int x = depth->width/2;
      int y = depth->height/2;
      printf("width= %d and height %d \n",x,y);
      int d = depth->imageData[x*2+y*640*2+1];
      printf("1st value is %d \n",d);
      d= d << 8;
      d= d+depth->imageData[x*2+y*640*2];
      return d;
    }
    IplImage *GlViewColor(IplImage *depth)
    {
        static IplImage *image = 0;
        if (!image) image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), 8, 3);
        unsigned char *depth_mid = (unsigned char*)(image->imageData);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 640*480; i++) {
            int lb = ((short *)depth->imageData)[i] % 256;
            int ub = ((short *)depth->imageData)[i] / 256;
            switch (ub) {
                case 0:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 255;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255-lb;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = 255-lb;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 255;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = lb;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 255-lb;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = lb;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = 255-lb;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = 255;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = 0;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = 255-lb;
                    break;
                default:
                    depth_mid[3*i+2] = 0;
                    depth_mid[3*i+1] = 0;
                    depth_mid[3*i+0] = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        while (cvWaitKey(100) != 27) {
            IplImage *image = freenect_sync_get_rgb_cv(0);
            if (!image) {
                printf("Error: Kinect not connected?\n");
                return -1;
            }
            cvCvtColor(image, image, CV_RGB2BGR);
            IplImage *depth = freenect_sync_get_depth_cv(0);
            if (!depth) {
                printf("Error: Kinect not connected?\n");
                return -1;
            }
            cvShowImage("RGB", image);
            //int d = getDist(depth);
            printf("value is %d \n",getDist(depth));
            cvShowImage("Depth", GlViewColor(depth));//GlViewColor(depth)

        }
        cvDestroyWindow("RGB");
        cvDestroyWindow("Depth");
        //cvReleaseImage(image);
        //cvReleaseImage(depth);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine. Scale the image of range (150-1147) to (0-255) and display it as gray scale. It will help you to have a better understanding of the image. Doing so will result in nearest object being dark-Colored and farthest being light-colored. It would be better than using *GlViewColor* function.